# How to Generate a complex XML using Spark-Xml

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-xml

I am trying to generate a complex xml from my JavaRDd< Book > and JavaRdd< Reviews > How can i club these two to generate below xml ?

```
<xml>
<library>
    <books>
        <book>
            <author>test</author>
        </book>
    </books>
    <reviews>
        <review>
            <id>1</id>
        </review>
    </reviews>
</library>
```

As you see, There is a Parent root Library which has child Books and Reviews.

Below is how i generate Book and Review Dataframe

```
DataFrame bookFrame = sqlCon.createDataFrame(bookRDD, Book.class);
DataFrame reviewFrame = sqlCon.createDataFrame(reviewRDD, Review.class);
```

I know to generate the xml and my doubt is particularly for having Library rootTag and having Books and Reviews as its Child.

I am using Java. but if you could point me right you can write Scala or Python example.

Comment: That won't work. Root tag is easy (there is option for that) but you cannot have different type of objects (different schemas) in a single `DataFrame`.

Comment: @user9613318 so should i perform a string concatenation after generating 2 different xml.? is that the only way out?

Comment: @user9613318 can you please help me with this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007809/spark-xml-array-within-an-array-in-dataframe-to-generate-xml

Comment: @user9613318 can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50131641/javax-xml-stream-xmlstreamexception-trying-to-output-second-root-spark-xml-spar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be the most efficient way of using Spark to do this, but code below works as you want. (Scala though, because my Java is a bit rusty)

```scala
import java.io.{File, PrintWriter}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SparkSession}
import scala.io.Source

val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .master("local[3]")
  .appName("test")
  .config("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

/* Some code to test */
case class Book(author: String)
case class Review(id: Int)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.OuterScopes.addOuterScope(this)


val bookFrame = List(
  Book("book1"),
  Book("book2"),
  Book("book3"),
  Book("book4"),
  Book("book5")
).toDS()


val reviewFrame = List(
  Review(1),
  Review(2),
  Review(3),
  Review(4)
).toDS()

/* End test code **/

// Using databricks api save as 1 big xml file (instead of many parts, using repartition)
// You don't have to use repartition, but each part-xxx file will wrap contents in the root tag, making it harder to concat later.
// And TBH it really doesn't matter that Spark is doing the merging here, since the combining of data is already on the master node only
bookFrame
  .repartition(1)
  .write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rootTag", "books")
  .option("rowTag", "book")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .save("/tmp/books/") // store to temp location

// Same for reviews
reviewFrame
  .repartition(1)
  .write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rootTag", "reviews")
  .option("rowTag", "review")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .save("/tmp/review") // store to temp location


def concatFiles(path:String):List[String] = {
  new File(path)
    .listFiles
    .filter(
      _.getName.startsWith("part") // get all part-xxx files only (should be only 1)
    )
    .flatMap(file => Source.fromFile(file.getAbsolutePath).getLines()) 
    .map("    " + _) // prefix with spaces to allow for new root level xml
    .toList
}

val lines = List("<xml>","<library>") ++ concatFiles("/tmp/books/") ++ concatFiles("/tmp/review/") ++ List("</library>")
new PrintWriter("/tmp/target.xml"){
  write(lines.mkString("\n"))
  close
}
```

Result:

```xml
<xml>
<library>
    <books>
        <book>
            <author>book1</author>
        </book>
        <book>
            <author>book2</author>
        </book>
        <book>
            <author>book3</author>
        </book>
        <book>
            <author>book4</author>
        </book>
        <book>
            <author>book5</author>
        </book>
    </books>
    <reviews>
        <review>
            <id>1</id>
        </review>
        <review>
            <id>2</id>
        </review>
        <review>
            <id>3</id>
        </review>
        <review>
            <id>4</id>
        </review>
    </reviews>
</library>
```

Another approach could be (to Only use spark) to create a new object 
`case class BookReview(books: List[Book], reviews: List[Review])` and store that to xml after `.collect()` all books & reviews into a single list.

Although then I wouldn't use spark to just process a single record (BookReview) but use a normal xml library (like xstream or so) to store this object.

---

Update
The List concat methods are not memory friendly, so using streams and buffers this could be a solution instead of the `concatFiles` method.

```scala
def outputConcatFiles(path: String, outputFile: File): Unit = {
  new File(path)
    .listFiles
    .filter(
      _.getName.startsWith("part") // get all part-xxx files only (should be only 1)
    )
    .foreach(file => {
      val writer = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile, true))
      val reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)))

      try {
        Stream.continually(reader.readLine())
          .takeWhile(_ != null)
          .foreach(line =>
            writer.write(s"    $line\n".getBytes)
          )
      } catch {
        case e: Exception => println(e.getMessage)
      } finally {
        writer.close()
        reader.close()
      }
    })
}

val outputFile = new File("/tmp/target2.xml")
new PrintWriter(outputFile) { write("<xml>\n<library>\n"); close}
outputConcatFiles("/tmp/books/", outputFile)
outputConcatFiles("/tmp/review/", outputFile)
new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile, true)) { append("</library>"); close}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I have a huge collection of records somewhere near five hundred thousands, hence i cannot take a List of it. On out current configuration it will throw OutOfMemory... but i will try out the concatenation that you have explained.

Comment: Good point. I've updated my answer to allow for FileStreams etc

Comment: can you please help me with this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007809/spark-xml-array-within-an-array-in-dataframe-to-generate-xml

Comment: Tom Lous https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50131641/javax-xml-stream-xmlstreamexception-trying-to-output-second-root-spark-xml-spar can you help me with this