# Spark-Xml: Array within an Array in Dataframe to generate XML

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-xml

I have a requirement to generate a XML which has a below structure

```html
<parent>
 <name>parent</name
    <childs>
 <child>
  <name>child1</name>
 </child>
 <child>
  <name>child1</name>
        <grandchilds>
  <grandchild>
   <name>grand1</name>
  </grandchild>
  <grandchild>
   <name>grand2</name>
  </grandchild>
  <grandchild>
   <name>grand3</name>
  </grandchild>
      </grandchilds>
 </child>
 <child>
  <name>child1</name>
 </child>
  </childs>
</parent>
```

As you see a parent will have child(s) and a child node may have grandchild(s) nodes.

https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml#conversion-from-dataframe-to-xml

I understand from spark-xml that when we have an nested array structure the data-frame should be as below

```html
+------------------------------------+
|                                   a|
+------------------------------------+
|[WrappedArray(aa), WrappedArray(bb)]|
+------------------------------------+
```

Can you please help me with this small example on how to make a flattened DataFrame for my desired xml. I am working on Spark 2.X Spark-Xml 0.4.5(Latest)

---

My Schema

```html
StructType categoryMapSchema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
          new StructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
          new StructField("childs", new StructType(new StructField[]{
              new StructField("child",
                  DataTypes.createArrayType(new StructType(new StructField[]{
                      new StructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true,          Metadata.empty()),
                      new StructField("grandchilds", new StructType(new StructField[]{
                          new StructField("grandchild",
                              DataTypes.createArrayType(new StructType(new StructField[]{
                                  new StructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true,
                                      Metadata.empty())
                              })), true, Metadata.empty())
                      }), true, Metadata.empty())
                  })), true, Metadata.empty())
          }), true, Metadata.empty()),
      });
```

My Row RDD data.. Not actual code, but somewhat like this.

```
final JavaRDD<Row> rowRdd = mapAttributes
      .map(parent -> {
        return RowFactory.create(
        parent.getParentName(),
        RowFactory.create(RowFactory.create((Object) parent.getChild))
        );

      });
```

What i have tried till now i have the WrappedArray within parent WrappedArray which does not work.

Comment: Spark is not the best tool to generate a single complex XML file structure. It is very good at distributed processing across workers and combining the results in 1 or more row/column-based files.
Your XML is a very nested deep structure. 
Why are you using Spark?

Comment: Besides... What is even the base dataframe/file structure which you are trying to convert to this XML? Can you show (part) of the dataframe?

Comment: @TomLous we have a spark project to generate a large feed for seo. our data is nearly hundred to five hundred thousand. With such big data and file to be generated. i found spark-xml to be the solution.

Comment: sc.createDataFrame(rowRDD, categoryMapSchema).... my rowRDD and custom schema is shown above in question.

Comment: 500k lines is a lot to do by hand, but an ordinary Java/Scala script, (given enough time) can produce the output you want as well. I really don't think Spark is the best solution. 
If you insist you should post a gist with the actual code & sample data (input), because its too hard for me to extrapolate from what you put here

Comment: @TomLous sorry it is not 500k lines. But its 500K node elements. Files will run to  500MBytes to 1Gb.